# Is there a way to get rid of my \vspace{} hack?

Tags: spacing, xetex, margins, itemize

I am creating my CV in TeX from scratch and I have come across multiple invisible lines that make my formatting inconsistent.

I have this command to make a bulleted list from delimited elements:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeitemize}{O{,} m}{
  \begin{itemize}
  \xyz_make_items:nn {#1} {#2}
  \end{itemize}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_xyz_input_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xyz_make_items:nn #1 #2{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_xyz_input_seq {#1} {#2}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_xyz_input_seq {\item ##1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The problem is that even though I have added the code `\setlist{nolistsep,leftmargin=*}` there is still space beneath my list so I am forced to change it to this:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeitemize}{O{,} m}{
  \begin{itemize}
  \xyz_make_items:nn {#1} {#2}
  \end{itemize}
  \vspace{-2ex}% remove extra space
 }

\seq_new:N \l_xyz_input_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xyz_make_items:nn #1 #2{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_xyz_input_seq {#1} {#2}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_xyz_input_seq {\item ##1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Compilable example:

**cv.cls**

```
\ProvidesClass{cv}[2015/06/20 v1.0 CV class]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Class and packages
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\LoadClass[10pt,a4paper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\RequirePackage[left=0.63in,top=0.5in,right=0.63in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry} % Document margins
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{setspace}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Metrics and fonts
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlist{nolistsep,leftmargin=*}

\setstretch{1.2} % for custom spacing
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Colours
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{main}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{secondary}{HTML}{A6A6A6}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Variables
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newdimen{\defaultlinespacing}
%\setlength{\defaultlinespacing}{12.5pt}

\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Commands
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\DeclareRobustCommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=12.5}\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeitemize}{O{,} m}{
  \begin{itemize}
  \xyz_make_items:nn {#1} {#2}
  \end{itemize}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_xyz_input_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xyz_make_items:nn #1 #2{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_xyz_input_seq {#1} {#2}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_xyz_input_seq {\item ##1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\cvSection}[1]{ % name
  \section*{#1}
}

\newcommand{\cvSubsection}[5]{ % name, country, year, title, description list
 \subsection{\textbf{#1, #2} \hfill \textcolor{secondary}{#3}\\ \textit{#4}}
 \makeitemize[;]{#5}
  }

\newcommand{\cvProjectSubsection}[3]{ % name, year, description
 \subsection{\textbf{#1} \hfill \textcolor{secondary}{#2}\\ #3}
  }

\newcommand{\cvLeadershipSubsection}[2]{ % description, year
 \subsection{#1 \hfill \textcolor{secondary}{#2}}
  }

\newcommand{\cvSkillsSubsection}[2]{ % level, skills
 \textbf{#1:} #2
  }

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Formatting
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\titleformat{\section}         % Customise the \section command 
  {\large\bfseries}
  {}{0ex}
  {{\titlerule[0.75pt]}\\[-1ex]\smallcaps}                           % Can be used to insert code before the heading
  [\color{secondary}{\titlerule[0.25pt]}]                 % Inserts a horizontal line after the heading

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {}
  {}{0pt}
  {}

\titlespacing*{\section}
    {0pt}%   {0pt}
    {0pt}%   {6pt}
    {0pt}%   {2pt}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}
  {0pt}%{0pt}
  {0pt}%{2pt}
  {0pt}%{-4pt}
```

**cv.tex**

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{cv}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvSection{Education}
\cvSubsection
{University of X}{Y}{Fall 2010 -- Present}{blablabla}
{
blablabla;
blablablablablablablablabla;
blablablablablabla
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cvSection{Experience}
\cvSubsection{Z}{Y}{Jan 2015 -- Present}{Software Developer}
{
blablabla;
blablablablablablablablabla;
blablablablablablablablabla;
blablablablablablablablabla;
blablablablablabla
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a complete compilable example?

Comment: @egreg I added it.

Comment: I see no added space after the itemized list; try adding a word after the final closing brace of `\cvSubsection` and see. However, `nosep` should be used instead of `nolistsep`. The space you see is caused by the `\titlerule` in the following heading.

Comment: @egreg I would never even think that `\titlerule` had spacing above it... How would I go about removing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The space you see is caused by the section title, not by the list.

Change the `\titleformat`:

```
\titleformat{\section}         % Customise the \section command
  {\large\bfseries\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
  {}
  {0ex}
  {\hrule\smallcaps\strut}
  [\color{secondary}{\titlerule[0.25pt]}] % Inserts a horizontal line after the heading
```

For setting the example I removed the `\setstretch{1.2}` instruction and added a paragraph after the itemized list, to show the spacing is normal.

I also used Linux Libertine as font, since the default Latin Modern lacks boldface small caps.

[image]